Stripe Setup a token from api
I am new to stripe payments. From some reading, I got that it is a good idea to use the payment intent API. But this depends on UI. How do I go about writing an api that takes card info, calls stripe to get a token(is this is setup intent) and uses that to collect payment.

Briefly, setup intents are for collecting payment details without payment. If you're taking payment you would want to use a payment intent.
I suggest working your way through this guide to build out what you're asking for.
If you mean building your own UI to collect card details, that's not recommended and it comes with a considerable PCI compliance burden. You should reach out to Stripe support before embarking on that path.
